# WindowManager issue

Tags: android

I am trying to add SeekBar, TimePicker and several button to WindowManager so that there won't be any yellow background or looping picture after pressing on it or dragging it, like this
[image]

Is it possible?
My code:

```
view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.edit_or_new,null);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button6);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopSelf();
            }
        });
        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                Log.e("Point_1","onProgressChanged");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        layoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
        layoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH;
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.addView(view, layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because "theme"
add this line to your code before call `windowManager.addView(view, layoutParams);`

```
setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
```

if you don't have any theme in your `style.xml` add this :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This didn't work for, unfortunately. May be there is another way to make it normal? Also I add that view to WindowManager in Service.

Comment: try to move `setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);` to onCreate() method, and change `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH` to `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE`